# Windows 10 runs extremely slowly in Parallels 10

Tags: macos, windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I'm running Parallels 10 on a 2014 MacBook Pro with OS X El Capitan (10.11.6). I have five virtual machines set up for various versions of Windows (7, 8, and 10).

For some reason, my Windows 10 VM runs extremely slowly – it boots, but then everything grinds to a halt (the Mac overall, not just the VM). Often, the only way out is to force shutdown and reboot.

The VM itself is a completely clean copy [straight from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) (indeed, I can never get it to run fast enough to actually do anything with it). My four other VMs all run perfectly fine, obviously on the same hardware, and I have all five configured identically.

I know that Parallels 11 advertises that it's [ready for Windows 10](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/whats-new/), implying that previous versions aren't – but my Parallels 10 installation *does* list Windows 10 as an option in the VM configuration. So it would seem it's supported.

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or is the solution just to upgrade to Parallels 11 (even though in theory my current setup should work)?

Comment: I'd go for Parallels 11 - Win 10 works just fine on my machine, compared to earlier Win OSes. I don't have a true comparison, though, as I went straight to 11 as soon as it was released.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a better experience with Parallels 11 than I did with 10 so you might be worth considering an upgrade to improve the experienced.